# OData request show showing up in Fiddler (SharePoint & Silverlight 5)

Tags: odata, fiddler, silverlight-5.0

I've got a Silverlight 5 app that is calling an OData service (the OOTB one incuded with SharePoint 2010) to pull data back form a list. The site is secured using Windows Authentication. When I run my test I get prompted to login but the results always say there are zero results returned in the result set.

Now here's what's strange. I know there's data in the list (and when I manually plug in the OData request URL, I see results come back in the browser). When I watch Fiddler while running the test, I see a few requests for clientaccesspolicy.xml (all result in a 401 response)... then I login & it successfully obtains the clientaccesspolicy.xml file. However, even though the app says it ran the query and got zero results back, I don't see the actual OData service request in Fiddler (nothing after the successful call to clientaccesspolicy.xml.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
private DataServiceCollection<InstructorsItem> _dataCollection = new DataServiceCollection<InstructorsItem>();

private Action<IEnumerable<Instructor>> _callbackWithData;

/// <summary>
/// Retrieves a list of instructors from the data service.
/// </summary>
public void GetInstructors(Action<IEnumerable<Instructor>> callback) {
  // save callbacks
  ResetCallbacks();
  _callbackWithData = callback;

  // get the instructors
  var query = from instructor in IntranetContext.Instructors
              select instructor;

  // execute query
  RunQuery(query);
}

/// <summary>
/// Retrieves instructors from the data source based on the specified query.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="query">Query to execute</param>
private void RunQuery(IQueryable<InstructorsItem> query) {
  // clear the collection & register the load completed method
  _dataCollection.Clear();
  _dataCollection.LoadCompleted += OnLoadDataCompleted;

  // fire the load
  _dataCollection.LoadAsync(query.Take(5));
}

/// <summary>
/// Handler when the data has been loaded from the service.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
void OnLoadDataCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e) {
  // remove the event handler preventing double loads
  _dataCollection.LoadCompleted -= OnLoadDataCompleted;

  // convert the data to a generic list of objects
  var results = _dataCollection.ToList<InstructorsItem>();

  // TODO: convert results to local objects
  List<Instructor> convertedResults = new List<Instructor>();
  foreach (var item in results) {
    convertedResults.Add(new Instructor() { 
      SharePointId = item.Id,
      Name = item.Title
    });
  }

  // run the callback
  _callbackWithData(convertedResults);
}
```

And here's what the test runner looks like that's triggering it:

```
[TestMethod]
[Asynchronous]
[Description("Test loading instructors from the OData Intranet service.")]
public void TestGetInstructors() {
  bool asyncCallCompleted = false;
  List<Instructor> result = null;

  // call data service
  _dataService.GetInstructors(asyncResult => {
    asyncCallCompleted = true;
    result = new List<Instructor>(asyncResult);
  });

  // run test when call completed
  EnqueueConditional(() => asyncCallCompleted);
  EnqueueCallback(
    () => Assert.IsTrue(result.Count > 0, "Didn't retrieve any instructors."));
  EnqueueTestComplete();
}
```

Can't for the life of me figure out (1) why i'm not seeing the query showing up in Fiddler when it is saying there are no errors, in fact it says there are zero errors when running the test.

Comment: I think I found the root of my problem: security. Closer examination found that in the event args for my OnLoadDataCompleted event handler shows there's an error in the call. I've started another thread on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636243/calling-windows-auth-secured-odata-service-cross-domain-in-silverlight-5

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the server and client on the same machine, there is no external HTTP traffic so there is nothing for Fiddler to pick up.

Comment: Different machines... server is a production box an I'm working from my laptop.

Comment: I've been caught out by that one a few times so thought it was worth a suggestion. Does Fiddler pick up other HTTP Traffic?

Comment: Yup... picks everything else up and I've ensured that no filters are turned on. Also can see it catching traffic when I try to use the browser to hit the same OData service. This leads me to believe there's not an issue with Fiddler, but that my Silverlight app isn't making the call to the service... not sure why it would return zero results in the collection rather than an error... but sure seems like it isn't making the call to the service to me.

Comment: OK, I can confirm the service is not being called. Not sure why this didn't occur to me earlier, but I put in an invalid URL for the service endpoint (just changed *.svc" to ".zzz") and got the same response: no items returned int he collection. Ideas why it wouldn't call the service?

Comment: You're outside my field of expertise by this point, I'm afraid, but glad to have helped you narrow down your search.