# Calling Windows-Auth secured OData Service Cross Domain in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain, odata

I'm trying to call an OData service (the OOTB one included with SharePoint 2010) that's secured with Windows Authentication from a Silverlight 5 app. In my research ([specifically this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/05/10/odata-and-authentication-part-2-windows-authentication.aspx)) I saw somewhere where it says:

> Warning: While it is possible in Silverlight to do x-domain calls, so
>   long as the other domain has a correctly configured
>   ClientAccessPolicy.xml file, if the other domain needs you to logon,
>   there is no way to provide your credentials.

So my question is, is there really no way to call a OData service cross domain that's secured with Windows Auth? This seems to be what the above post is stating, but I find it hard to believe it just isn't possible...

Comment: Answering my own post to follow up on the research I found... Because NTLM is a negotation of each request, you can't do this very easily. I could override the generated DataContext proxy, but it would get pretty messy. Here's what the negotation looks like: http://www.innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own post to follow up on the research I found... Because NTLM is a negotation of each request, you can't do this very easily. I could override the generated DataContext proxy, but it would get pretty messy. Here's what the negotation looks like: innovation.ch/personal/ronald/ntlm.html